# Rotation based positioning not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an arrow that I shoot from my bow. I want to summon a particle a block below it and 2 blocks to the left. The following command works relative to me in any rotation:

```
/execute as CollidaCube positioned as @s rotated as @s positioned ~ ~-1 ~ run particle minecraft:falling_dust minecraft:sand ^2 ^ ^ 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.5 1
```

I set the executor to the arrow:

```
/execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=Sandstorm] ...
```

Shooting directly north south east or west works. However, the more I shoot it diagonally, the more the particle starts getting summoned behind the arrow.

Comment: Do you want the particle to continue to summon when the arrow flies so you get a line, or just once?

Comment: Also could you add the command used to get the tag on the arrow.

Comment: I have the command to summon the particles in a repeating command block, so it already does the trail.
`data merge entity @e[type=arrow,nbt={damage:37d},limit=1] {damage:5d,Tags:["Sandstorm"],NoGravity:1b}`
after i shoot it, i fly in front of the arrow to stop it. Wouldn't recommend charging the bow much lol @SemlanBakelsen

Comment: I discovered that the arrow rotation isn't the same as other entities. It goes in the opposite direction. if the player has a rotation of 90 in one direction the arrow will have a -90. I'm unable to find a way to fix the problem.